# I have trouble with Python outputting "None" with every line of output

Tags: python

I am trying to make python cipher and decipher text with the Playfair method. But I hit a roadblock because it seems to output "None" with every line out output.
I'd be grateful if anyone tells me why it's doing so.
(This is my first post, so please bear with any mistakes I might have made).
My code:

```
def cip():
    key=input(print("Please Enter Keyword: "))
    return key

def inp():
    c = int(input(print("1.Cipher text \n2.Exit\n\t>>")))
    if c==1:
        cip()
    else:
        exit
inp()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Code\Py programs>python -u "c:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Code\Py programs\Playfair.py"
1.Cipher text
2.Exit
        >>
None1
Please Enter Keyword:
NoneTron
```

Comment: What is `decip()`? Please provide a [mcve]. Also -- your `cip()` function doesn't really seem to be a cipher function at all.

Comment: ``input`` already writes its message to the console. Use ``input("Please Enter Keyword: ")`` instead of ``input(print("Please Enter Keyword: "))``.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your use of `print()` in the `input()` call.

```
c = int(input(print("1.Cipher text \n2.De-cipher text\n3.Exit\n\t>>")))
              ^^^^^
```

`print()` prints its argument, and returns `None`. `input()` uses the value of its argument as the prompt, so it's printing `None` as the prompt.

Just pass a prompt string to `input()`, don't call `print()`

```
c = int(input("1.Cipher text \n2.De-cipher text\n3.Exit\n\t>>"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you use input with print in it. Print should be outside.

```
def cip():
    print("Please Enter Keyword: ")
    key=input()
    return key

def inp():

    print("1.Cipher text \n2.De-cipher text\n3.Exit\n\t>>")
    c = int(input())
    if c==1:
        cip()
    elif c==2:
        decip()
    else:
        exit

inp()
```

You could also put the string in input(), like this:

```
c = int(input("1.Cipher text \n2.De-cipher text\n3.Exit\n\t>>"))
```